# memcached не принимает большие данные

Tags: php, memcached

Есть большой json-файл(примерно, 7,5 мегабайт), который подгружается с диска и декодируется примерно 3 секунды. Я захотел это исправить и положить декодированный в многомерный массив json в memcached, чтобы повысить скорость исполнения скрипта:

```
$cached_cities = $memcached->get('decoded-cities');
if($cached_cities) {
    $cities = $cached_cities;
} else {
    $uncached_cities = json_decode(file_get_contents('../../assets/json/cities.json'), true);
    $memcached->set('decoded-cities', $uncached_cities, 604800);
    $cities = $uncached_cities;
}
```

Но это не работает нифига. Создал тестовый скрипт, положил в ключ строчку `'foo-bar'` - положилось. А мой массив ни в какую в кэш не лезет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он не принимает, потому что ограничение по умолчанию на 1 запись 1 мб. Измените параметры запуска или конфиг как тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/29227471/5996783

Comment: На самом деле в /etc/memcached.conf указан параметр `-m 128`. Не это ли оно?

Comment: Нет. Насколько помню это сколько выделать памяти на storage

Answer (score 2):

У вас не получится сколько-нибудь существенно выиграть таким образом, так как при сохранении в memcached ваш массив будет снова сериализован. Затем снова рассериализован. То есть, вы натолкнётесь на ту же самую проблему, но с другим видом сериализации.

Лучшим решением было бы хранить результат чтения JSON сразу в файле PHP:

```
file_put_contents('cache.php', '<?php return '.var_export($array, true).';');
```

Этот шаг следует делать не каждый раз, а только при обновлении JSON файла. Например, делая так при сборке проекта:

```
if (!is_file('cache.php') || filemtime('data.json') > filemtime('cache.php')) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
    file_put_contents('cache.php', '<?php return '.var_export($data, true).';');
}
```

Использовать сохранённые таким образом данные проще простого:

```
$data = include 'cache.php';
```

Если вы используете кеш инструкций, что скорее всего, то загрузка данных из такого файла будет происходить моментально.

Если же вам обычно не нужны все-все данные из этого файла, или вы собираетесь делать по ним выборку, то ещё лучше будет хранить данные в БД.

Если же вы думаете что сможете сделать проект быстрее за счёт отказа от БД, то подумайте хорошо. Современные БД очень оптимально работают с данными: вам нужно очень постараться чтобы обогнать их. Лучше будет сначала измерить скорость поиска в БД с необходимыми индексами прежде чем пытаться изобрести очередной велосипед.

В вашем случае обычные БД вроде MySQL будут работать быстрее хотя бы потому что им не нужно загружать в память весь набор данных *при каждом запросе*.

Comment: Хм, я думал, что memcached как раз нужен для того, чтобы хранить в нём что-то, чтобы в нужный момент взять это из быстрой памяти. В самом деле, мне нужно делать выборку из этого большого json-массива. Думаете, моя Postgre сможет мне обеспечить быструю выборку? Нужно до полусекунды сделать от 10 до 30 выборок.

Comment: Не знаю насчёт PostgreSQL, но для MySQL тридцать поисковых запросов по прогретой базе в 10 мб за 0,5 секунды - семечки. Даже без индексов. Вряд ли вы сможете то же самое сделать быстрее в коде. Тем более в PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в php.ini не настроен, возможно что это проблема связаная, с тем что сервер memcahed не может принимать Json, эта настройка опять же есть в php.ini. 
Попробуйте прочесть это - http://php.net/manual/ru/memcached.setup.php и это - http://php.net/manual/ru/memcached.configuration.php

Comment: В php.ini нет ни единого упоминания memcached.

Comment: Вот тут вы не правы, [http://php.net/manual/ru/memcached.configuration.php#ini.memcached.sess-binary](http://php.net/manual/ru/memcached.configuration.php#ini.memcached.sess-binary).